# Datagridview allowing user to add or delete rows with a combo box column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, binding

I need to set a DataGridView based on two classes, as follows

```
public class Selection 
{
    public string Display { get; protected set; }
    public int Value { get; protected set; }

    public Selection( string d, int v)
    {
        Display = d; Value = v;
    }
}

public class TestData
{
    public Selection Selection { get; protected set; }
    public int Quantity { get; protected set; }

    public TestData( Selection sel, int q)
    {
        Selection = sel;
        Quantity = q;
    }
}
```

The TestData objects are the rows. The user must choose a Selection from a ComboBox column populated from a List or something alike.
But the TestData collection must be a BindingList to allow adding or deleting rows, and as such, is the datagrid DataSource. 
Until now, I´m trying to set de grid with the following code

```
    List<Selection> getSelectionList()
    {
        List<Selection> result = new List<Selection>();

        result.Add(new Selection("Zero", 0));
        result.Add(new Selection("One", 10));
        result.Add(new Selection("Two", 20));
        result.Add(new Selection("Three", 30));
        result.Add(new Selection("Four", 40));
        result.Add(new Selection("Five", 50));
        result.Add(new Selection("Six", 60));

        return result;
    }

    List<TestData> getTestDataList(List<Selection> reference)
    {
        List<TestData> result = new List<TestData>();
        result.Add(new TestData(reference[1], 10));

        return result;
    }

................
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[0];
        List<Selection> list = getSelectionList();
        combo.DataSource = list;
        combo.DisplayMember = "Display";
        combo.ValueMember = "Value";

        BindingList<TestData> source = new BindingList<TestData>(getTestDataList(list)) { AllowEdit = true, AllowNew = true, AllowRemove = true };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
................
```

but the result is annoying: 
a) The grid shows two rows (even if I set only one element in the TestData list)
b) The combo cells have no data in them.

How can I solve this?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add two lines:

```
string key = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)combo.SelectedItem).Key;
string value = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)combo.SelectedItem).Value;
```

Comment: Where or to which object do I need to add those lines?